# Is there a quest that requires the other Butcherblock Bandits' body parts?

Tags: everquest

I'm playing [Project 1999](http://wiki.project1999.com/Project1999:About), the emulator for classic EverQuest.  I remember fondly back in the day camping out the dwarf bandits in Butcherblock as a youngling.

It seems like, in the 15 years hence, no one still knows what to do with some of the Lore, No Trade unique body part items that you can grab off some of the bandits.

I'm not talking about the Dunfires.  It's very well established [you can trade their four tongues in to Diggins in Kaladim for the Parrying Pick](http://wiki.project1999.com/Parrying_Pick_Quest).

I'm talking about [Qued's tongue](http://wiki.project1999.com/Qued%27s_Tongue), [Stump Rundl's gnoll paw "hand"](http://wiki.project1999.com/Gnoll_Paw), and Peg Leg's... [small wooden leg](http://wiki.project1999.com/Small_Wooden_Leg).

Does anyone know what these are used for?  Is there a way to conclusively find out - such as getting the complete quest text for classic EQ?

Answer (score 3):

Allakhazam was the resource I used back in the day.  Apparently that leg never got a quest.

http://everquest.allakhazam.com/db/item.html?item=17166

Comment: So it would seem, but I'm looking for a conclusive answer.

Comment: @mcw0933 Short of stealing a database from whatever became of SOE, this is probably as definitive as you are going to get

Comment: Which is why I'm hopeful someone affiliated with Project 1999 can put this to bed ;)

Answer (score 1):

The Dunfires, the parrying pick quest, and Qued, were all added in the same patch in May 1999. Source here:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/alt.games.everquest/qG0iH2UvQ5g/discussion

Most likely what happened is miscommunication at Verant, all the quest items were created at the same time (Dunfire and Qued tongues), but the quest writer never implemented the Qued one.

They weren't in the habit of deleting things because EQ was like a bowl of spaghetti and nobody was 100% sure without deep investigation what might be used where. Safer to just leave it.

That's about as definitive as you will likely get without looking up the original quest developers on LinkedIn (if they're still even alive).